# Differences between between concepts related to Gödel's Incompleteness theorems: self-referencing, diagonalization and fixed point theorem?

Tags: logic, fixed-point-theorems, incompleteness

I am studying the proof of Gödel's first Incompleteness theorem at the moment and I don't understand the differences between self-referencing, diagonalization and fixed point related to Gödel's proof.

In my opinion, they all mean taking the Gödel number of a formula as an argument into the formula itself.

Can someone please explain me the differences?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoever down-voted should provide a reason.

Comment: @Coopi Have you considered accepting some answers for your earlier questions?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably help if you provide instances of each. But if you're just talking about their use in Gödel incompleteness theorems, then I suppose they all mean different aspects of the same thing. Application of the fixed point lemma is often referred to as diagonalization (of a given formula), and then that formula is said to be referring to itself.

I recommend:

Raymond Smullyan, 1994. *Diagonalization and Self-Reference*. Oxford Univ. Press.

Raymond Smullyan, 1991. *Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems*. Oxford Univ. Press.